# String[] or ArrayList better as Key in HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, arraylist

So I need to choose between

1. `HashMap<String[], Object>`
2. `HashMap<ArrayList<String>,Object>`

My input Parameter is: `ArrayList<String> in`.

The whole `ArrayList<String> in` cannot be the key, since it does contain elements, which are not supposed to be like a *Primary Key in a database*. I do know, that the first `n` elements of the incoming `ArrayList<String> in` supposed to be the *primary Keys*.

Which one would be faster?

**Scenario:**

```
HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Object> hmAL = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String[], Object> hmSA = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<>(); 
fillWithStuff(in);

//Which one would be faster?
getObject(in,hmAL,5);
getObject(in,hmSA,5);
```

**With Option 1:**

```
private Object getObject(ArrayList<String> in, HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Object> hm, int n){
  return hm.get(in.sublist(0,n));
}
```

**With Option 2:**

```
private Object getObject(ArrayList<String> in, HashMap<String[], Object> hm, int n){
String[] temp = new String[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  temp[i]=in.get(i);

  return hm.get(temp);
}
```

**Considering:**

1. Which is faster? Short the list, or copy to an array?
2. I'm wondering, which hash (since it is a HashMap) would be faster. Hashing of a ArrayList, or an equal-sized array. Or doesn't it make any difference?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use a container as a key in a `HashMap`.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea?

Comment: Because the contents of the container could be changed after the key has been inserted, and Java does not have `const` objects.

Comment: You might find useful Guava Multimap

Comment: @Fede: is there something like an inverse Guava MultiMap? Like: with Multiple Keys for one Value?

Comment: @Joel Multimap is exactly that, you can map `A->1`, `A->2`, `B->1` and `A->3`, so when you do a `GET(A)` you will receive a list with `1,2,3`

Comment: @Fede: yes, but I want multible keys to lead to one value. Something like: `(A && B)-> 1`. Noticing, that A and B are `String` and not `bool`

Answer (score 2):

Using `String[]` is not a good idea because it does not implement `hashCode()`. This means if you have 2 string arrays which are different objects but with the exact same values, the map will not find it.

The implementation of 'hashCode` seems to use each of the string elements hashcode so the lookup in a map would succeed. So I'd go with this one.

That said, I would rather build a key myself based on the objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

### Dealing with copying only

The `subList` method is implemented very efficiently in Java 7+, not requiring any copying at all. It simply returns a view directly onto the original array. Thus, in Java 7+, it will be faster than the copy element by element method. However, in Java 6, both ways are essentially equivalent.

### Dealing with the method as a whole

If you look at the whole method, your choice is no longer a choice. If you want the method to function, you will have to use the first implementation. Array `hashCode()` does not look at the elements inside it---only the identity of the array. Because you are creating the array in your method, the `Map.get()` will necessary return `null`.

On the other hand, the `List.hashCode()` method runs a hash on all of the contained elements, meaning that it will successfully match if all of the contained elements are the same.

Your choice is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on above two answers, I have tested in Java 7 and found on an average with list it's 50 times faster with `2000000` total elements and `1000000` elements which participate in calculating `hashcode` i.e. primary keys (hypothetical number). Below is the program.

```
public class TestHashing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Object> hmAL = new HashMap();
        HashMap<String[], Object> hmSA = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<>();
        fillWithStuff(in);

        // Which one would be faster?
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        getObject(in, hmAL, 1000000);
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        long firstTime = (end-start);
        System.out.println("firstTime :: "+ firstTime);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        getObject1(in, hmSA, 1000000);
        end = System.nanoTime();

        long secondTime = (end-start);

        System.out.println("secondTime :: "+ secondTime);

       System.out.println("First is faster by "+ secondTime/firstTime);
    }

    private static void fillWithStuff(ArrayList<String> in) {
        for(int i =0; i< 2000000; i++) {
            in.add(i+"");
        }
    }

    private static Object getObject(ArrayList<String> in,
            HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Object> hm, int n) {
        return hm.get(in.subList(0, n));
    }

    private static Object getObject1(ArrayList<String> in, HashMap<String[], Object> hm, int n){
        String[] temp = new String[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
          temp[i]=in.get(i);

          return hm.get(temp);
        }
}
```

> Output

```
firstTime :: 218000
secondTime :: 11627000
First is faster by 53
```